# How to save/open DataTable to file as it is?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I am developing app for translating resources of Android project. Later, after editing I want to save whole project. And i want to save DataTable to file and then open it later with appropriate headers and etc.

---

**How can I implement this?**

[image: My app]

GitHub link if someone interested: https://github.com/metjka/xmltanslate

Answer (score 1):

You can save a `DataTable` or `DataSet` class as an xml file just by calling it's `WriteXml` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hyx9hb4(v=vs.110).aspx).